# Setting a preselected item for html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a a html.dropdownlistfor which list around 900 items

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentWebContentID, null, "Choose...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I want it to have a preselected item and thought the 3rd parameter ("Choose...") was for this.

So I arranged for a ViewBag variable to hold a value (ChosenParentWebContentId)
like this

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            if (!AccountController.IsInRole(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ParentWebContentID = GetWebContentListwithGroup(null);
            if(id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ChosenParentWebContentID = db.WebContent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WebContentID == id).ParentWebContentID;
            }

            ViewBag.WebContentTypeID = db.WebContentType.ToList();
            ViewBag.ContentTypeID = id;
            ViewBag.LanguageCode = new SelectList(db.WebLanguage, "LanguageCode", "DisplayName");
            ViewBag.CreatedByUserID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email");
            ViewBag.LastEditedByUserID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email");

            ViewBag.DetailList = db.WebContentDetail.Where(x => x.WebContentID == id).ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

I tried changing "choose..." with the ViewBag variable but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

I couldn't find any help on other examples around internet.

Comment: The 3rd parameter is for generating the `null` label option. Do not use `ViewBag` (use a view model) and you need to bind your dropdown to a model property - e.g. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Options. "Choose...", new { .. })`. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ewluv) for an example

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Html.DropDownListFor` (or any of the `*For` family of helpers), the value comes from the value of the bound property. Actually, it's a little more complex than that. The value comes from the value of the bound property *in `ModelState`*.

So, if you want an item to be automatically selected, then you need to set `ParentWebContentID` to the value you want selected. Plain and simple. However, once a post is made, the select value will always be what was posted, even if you set `ParentWebContentID` to a different value. Also worth bearing in mind: `Request`, `ViewBag` and `ViewData` all participate in defining the values in `ModelState`. As a result, if for example you had an action that had a param named `parentWebContentID` (case-insensitive), that value from the request would always take precedence over any value you set on the model explicitly.